# How to log error and info messages separately into syslog with log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

log4j.properties:

```
# configure the root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG

# configure Syslog facility LOCAL6 appender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.facility=LOCAL6
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern="MyApp: %d\{ISO8601\}%m\n"
```

logger class

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jAuditLogger {
    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Log4jAuditLogger.class);

    public static void log(String message) {
        LOG.info(message);
    }
}
```

I want to log info (these are audit messages, i don't want to log error messages here) messages into SYSLOG LOCAL6, and to log error messages(these are internal error messages of the java program) into SYSLOG LOCAL7.

How should I extend this class and configuration file to do this?

I use log4j 1.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your log4j.properties another appender:

```
# configure the root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG, SYSLOG7

# configure Syslog facility LOCAL6 appender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.facility=LOCAL6
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern="MyApp: %d\{ISO8601\}%m\n"

# configure Syslog facility LOCAL7 appender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG7=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG7.threshold=ERROR
#                                  vv change to whatever the host is
log4j.appender.SYSLOG7.syslogHost=localhost 
log4j.appender.SYSLOG7.facility=LOCAL7
log4j.appender.SYSLOG7.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG7.layout.conversionPattern="MyApp: %d\{ISO8601\}%m\n"
```

Edit regarding comment:

If SYSLOG7 shall only log ERROR (and higher): set the threshold to ERROR level. All messages logged with a lower level won't show.

Tricky part is to show only low levels in Syslog:

You can use a filter to log only messages "lower" than e.g. `ERROR` level.

**In log4j 2 : The filter is not supported by PropertyConfigurator. So you must change to XML config to use it**. See [log4j-Wiki about filters](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/LogToAppenderByLevel?highlight=%28filter%29).

Example "specific level"

```
<appender name="info-out" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"> 
            <param name="File" value="info.log"/> 
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/> 
            </layout> 
            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
                    <param name="LevelToMatch" value="info" />
                    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
            </filter>
            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" />
</appender>
```

Or "Level range"

```
<appender name="info-out" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"> 
            <param name="File" value="info.log"/> 
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/> 
            </layout> 
            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
                    <param name="LevelMax" value="info"/>
                    <param name="LevelMin" value="info"/>
                    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
            </filter>
</appender>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the threshold of SYSLOG7 appender be ERROR? How can I choose in the Java code which appender I do want to use? Is it enough to just write LOG.error("msg"); ? I would like to log the info messages only in SYSLOG, and the error messages only in SYSLOG7.

Comment: If 7 shall only show ERROR messages (and higher) then simply set the Threahsold, yes. The tricky part is for 6 to **not** show ERROR messages. You could configure a Filter but if I remember correctly you'd need to change to xml config for Filters to be available.

Comment: Maybe this is a workaround in log4j 2, but in 1.2 you can do this without an xml file too. The key was really the LevelMin and LevelMax filter. Later I realized, that If i want to extend this logger with additional functionality, it's advised to define more loggers. Like, when you need to log the same severity level log messages into different facilities depending on their properties.

Comment: Hi, if I route log4j logs to Rsyslog (with the threshold of error), will I still get also the logs that I got until now, written straight as configured in log4j.xml? Also, I see that I don't have a file called log4j.properties in my machine.

Comment: @Tomer Filters work on Appenders, i.e. one specific Appender. So other Appenders won't be affected. If you do not have a log4j.properties, you'll probably have a log4j.xml.

Comment: @BlackCat Ah, I see you added the Version info after I wrote the answer. Yes, in 1.2 it seems to work without xml. You should accept one of the answers (even if it will be your own) to improve your questions/accepted answers ratio.

Comment: @Fildor First of all I forgot to say thanks for the answer above and here. sounds good, another question is: in my java project I send logs to all kinds of appenders. How do I log to Syslog all logs that are written to those appenders from "error" level and higher without touching the code?

Comment: @Tomer Please ask a new question about that, so other users with same problem may find it.

Comment: Cool I will create a new question

Comment: Hi @Fildor can you help me with this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954339/write-logs-from-existing-log4j-appenders-all-logs-with-debug-level-error-or-hi

Answer (score 0):

In log4j 1.2 we can use filters in the property file. For full separation and better customization I think it's advised to define more loggers.

**My example:**

**log4j.properties:**

```
# configure the root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
log4j.logger.auditLogger=INFO,SYSAUDIT
log4j.logger.appLogger=INFO,SYSAPPINFO,SYSAPPERR

log4j.additivity.auditLogger=false
log4j.additivity.appLogger=false

# SYSAUDIT appender
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT.facility=LOCAL6
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT.layout.conversionPattern=Audit Info: %d\{ISO8601\} %m\n
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT.filter.a.LevelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSAUDIT.filter.a.LevelMax=INFO

# SYSAPPINFO appender
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO.facility=LOCAL5
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO.layout.conversionPattern=App Info: %d\{ISO8601\} %m\n
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO.filter.a.LevelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSAPPINFO.filter.a.LevelMax=INFO

# SYSAPPERR appender
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR.threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR.facility=LOCAL5
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR.layout.conversionPattern=App Error: %d\{ISO8601\} %m\n
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR.filter.a.LevelMin=ERROR
log4j.appender.SYSAPPERR.filter.a.LevelMax=ERROR
```

**Log4jLogger class:**

```
public class Log4jLogger {
    private static Logger AUDITLOGGER = Logger.getLogger("auditLogger");
    private static Logger APPLOGGER = Logger.getLogger("appLogger");

    public static void audit(String message)
    {
        AUDITLOGGER.info(message);
    }

    public static void error(String message)
    {
        APPLOGGER.error(message);
    }

    public static void info(String message)
    {
        APPLOGGER.info(message);
    }
}
```